# How can i change ruby version to default on mac os x?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I installed rbenv with brew but when i uninstall it nothing changes. Here is output:

```
$ which -a ruby
/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: _it nothing changes_ - what changes you expect?

Comment: @Зелёный

I expect something like that

$ which -a ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/148)

If you used Homebrew, then brew uninstall rbenv.

rm -rf ~/.rbenv and then remove whatever you added to your shell's start-up files.

Comment: removing rbenv-related lines in ~/.bash_profile was what i didn't notice. thanks @anquegi